Change Window Title When Start PowerShell with Sudo.exe
I tried starting powershell with Sudo for Windows from CMD or Batch. Works fine. A PowerShell window opens with administrator rights:
rem CMD/BAT
sudo.exe start powershell.exe


Then, I tried adding a command to change the WindowTitle, for CMD worked:
sudo.exe cmd.exe /k "TITLE Command Prompt"

but I tried for PowerShell to change it, it didn't worked:
rem CMD/BAT
sudo.exe start powershell.exe -Command "$Host.UI.RawUI.Windowtitle = 'Windows Powershell'"

so, what is the correct writing for PowerShell, so that when it opens, the title looks like this?


"it didn't work for PowerShell"- You need to provide a more detailed description other than "it didn't work" considering sudo only exists pre-release versions of Windows.

@Ramhound I mean set windowtitle of PowerShell

It may just be my OCD, but it doesn't look right to me. Could you please try start sudo.exe powershell.exe ..., (or probably for robustness start "" sudo.exe powershell.exe ...), instead, and provide feedback on both of your PowerShell examples. Although if you're using the Start command anyhow, what about using its title option, and placing it inside those currently empty doublequotes.

@Compo PowerShell pinned in taskbar. Shift, then right-click mouse, > run as administrator

Refer to Start /? of CMD: START ["title"] [command/program].
Just add sudo.exe at beginning.
sudo.exe start "Windows PowerShell" powershell.exe
sudo.exe start "PowerShell 7" pwsh.exe
sudo.exe start "Command Prompt" cmd.exe

screenshot
Of course, getting administrator rights with sudo.exe is more practical and faster than other methods.

Thanks, Brother....

I told you that eleven hours earlier, Mr.Key7: "Although if you're using the Start command anyhow, what about using its title option".

@Compo Right. apparently it doesn't change the start /? format. just add sudo.exe at the beginning. If start sudo.exe powershell.exe will opened in sudo.exe console. if sudo.exe start powershell.exe, will in powershell console. thanks.

I know how start works Mr.Key7, thankyou. My initial queries were to try to understand how sudo.exe is running the internal cmd.exe command start. Nonetheless, I told you about the title option of the start command in my comment, yet you appear not to have tried it.

@Compo Perhaps I don't really understand what you mean in that comment. Sorry, because English is not my mother language.

Put simply, because you were "using the Start command", I told you, "what about using its title option". This answer says to use START ["title"]. I was simply making the point that my advice should have been sufficient for you to try yourself, rather that wait half a day more for someone to type output from start /? and some examples for you.
